# React-based alternative to Wordpress + Elementor

Tags: cms, wordpress, react

I'd like to provide one of my clients the ability to make minor content changes on a light feature website, and easily add minor features in the future with no-code options. The main capabilities of their site will be:

- star ratings on products
- reviews
- comments, up/down voting

I'm leaning towards Wordpress headless CMS and with Elementor or similar for themes and drag/drop UI editor. Before I go that route, what other similar tool stacks exist that use React components and CMS for React that can offer similar capabilities for non-developers to maintain and make minor enhancements?
My reason for looking for this alternative is so that if the client hires a dev team in the future, they have the flexibility to build on top of a modern web dev stack.